# ArchLinux installation - missing tools

Tags: installation, arch-linux, packages, fdisk

I'm trying to install ArchLinux by following [the beginners' guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) on the Arch wiki. I managed to establish a internet connection, but right now I'm stuck with preparing the storage drive. Whenever I try to use 'sgdisk' or 'fdisk' (even editing for eg. 'nano') I get messages like 'sh:*tool-name*: not found'. Answers to similar questions on the internet mentioned that you have to be root, which I am.

That said, does Arch require additional package(s) to be fully installed? Or are those tools just disabled at the moment?

EDIT:
People on other forums recommended to use the path, so: /sbin/fdisk. Yet, it does not work...

```
>>>fdisk -l /dev/sda
sh: fdisk: not found
>>>/sbin/fdisk -l /dev/sda
sh: /sbin/fdisk: not found
```

Articles suggested to use "su -":

```
>>>su -
sh: su: not found
>>>sudo
sh: sudo: not found
```

The beginners' guide above clearly mentions that fdisk variants are included in the install medium.

Answer (score 1):

Man - I finally managed to fix it. After going through the beginners' guide over and over again, I was sure that there was a problem with the installation medium. First I used USBwriter to write the .iso file to a USB flash drive. There must have been an issue with the program or with the USB. Then I took a DVD-RW and used the standard Windows 8 tool to burn the .iso to the disk.

When done, I inserted the DVD into my laptop and everything worked fine. All tools I needed were available. The DVD fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The true root of this problem is that fdisk is not a global command. You either have to add it to your path or find where it is located in your file structure.